# Formatting numbers through ExtJS or javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am using string.Format() to format some numbers at the server side.

```
double dd = 15453434.5345;
            Console.Write(String.Format("{0:N0}", dd));
            Console.Read();
```

Above code generates:

> 15,453,435

The number is rounded off and we can see comma separator. How can I achieve this using ExtJS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [Ext.util.Format](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.util.Format).

This class is a centralized place for formatting functions. It includes functions to format various different types of data, such as text, dates and numeric values.

Options include:

- thousandSeparator
- decimalSeparator
- currenyPrecision
- currencySign
- currencyAtEnd

Example:

```
Ext.util.Format.thousandSeparator = ',';
Ext.util.Format.decimalSeparator = ',';
var num = (15453434.5345).toFixed(0);

//And then:
Ext.util.Format.number(num, '0,000.00'); //outputs 15,453,435
```

Comment: Will it work even if the browser culture changes? Since I am explicityly specifying the thousand separator and decimal speparator, I assume thousand separator and decimal speparator wont changed based on broswer culture.

Comment: If you specify like this then it won't change, but if you need it to change then configure this options in localization.

Comment: There's not really any reason to use `/i`, here. Or ever... really.

Comment: @DavorZubak: How can I use this to change the value in a grid cell. I know i can use renderer function. function renderGridCells(value, metadata, record, rowIndex, colIndex, str, gridView) { return value; } But I am not sure how can i say var num = value.toFixed(0); ? would that work ?

Comment: just use 'value.toFixed(0)' where you would use 'value'

Comment: Ext.util.Format.number((15453434.5345).toFixed(0), '0,000.00');